# why sql server not showing in odbc list?

Tags: sql-server

i have sql server 2008 r2 installed in my server on network and i want to make odbc connection to this server from other device on network, but the problem that the sql server not show in the odbc list  .
note : the pc is pinging the server and the port 1433 is opened on the server.

Comment: Are you talking about the "Data Sources (ODBC)" window under Control Panel -> Administrative Tools?  If so, those have to be created manually, they don't automatically generate.

Comment: Have you installed the SQL Server Native Client on the client PC?

Answer (score 8):

You should not have to install the SQL Server Native Client. Windows Operating System includes a SQL Server driver.

You might not be seeing the server in the list because the DBA has disabled [SQL Server Browser Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087%28v=SQL.105%29). If this service is stopped it does not broadcast its availability on the network.

If this is the case you will need to manually type in the server/instance you are wanting to connect to.

Comment: sql browser service is running but the pc in different subnet of server . gow i cn add it manual

Comment: If you are on a different subnet it is likely that is the reason. The drop-down field where you stated the server was not showing up should also be a free-form field to manually enter the server or named instance.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me. Viewed 33k times and only 5 upvotes ...

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a 64-bit version of Windows, then there are two separate ODBC Admin Tools - there is a 32-bit version and a 64-bit version.

This blog post *([32 bit ODBC drivers on 64 bit Windows](http://weblogs.asp.net/guybarrette/archive/2010/05/10/32-bit-odbc-drivers-on-64-bit-windows.aspx))* explains how to access each of them:

> When you install a 32 bit ODBC driver on a 64 bit Windows it doesn’t show up in the Data Sources admin tool because this tool displays only 64 bit drivers.
>
> You can manage a 32 bit ODBC driver on a 64 bit Windows using the 32 bit Data Sources admin tool located here: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`
>
> - 64 bit software can’t use 32 bit ODBC drivers
> - 32 bit software installed on a 64 bit Windows can use 32 bit ODBC drivers

Comment: I tried to locate sysWOW64 in windows 10 folder but It seems it doesn't exist in windows folder..I need it in order to create a driver for 32bit

Comment: The `odbcad32.exe` is present on my Windows 10 computer ([example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNsf2.png)). Perhaps you are not seeing it because you need to enable the [Show Hidden Files and Folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028316/windows-view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-10) option.